# Metrics not showing properly with gauge type in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, metricbeat

My area and line charts properly show the average of `system.cpu.user.pct` and `system.memory.used.pct`.  0.4 as 40%

[image]

However, when I use gauge type visualization, it doesn't show the data properly. Gauge expresses 0.4 not as 40% but seems to take it as 0.4 percent.

[image]

**I want to multiply the value of `system.cpu.user.pct` and `system.memory.used.pct` by 100 to solve this problem**

[image]

I have a feeling that maybe I could do something here. Value * 100 ? 
Can anyone give me tips?

Comment: I don't think that this is the right approach to solve this "issue".
Can you please check if percentage mode is enabled in the options tab?

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill  hey I was just writing my answer. I used the percentage mode. It didn't fix anything. :(

Comment: @JinLee I want to do the same but on my own project, will you please share some resource/help by which I can create my endpoints of my Metricbeat. I am struggling in getting  system variable like CPU/Memory/diskio etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I mentioned in the comments section above, executions of scripts are always slowing down your queries since the output has to be calculated every time your dataset updates.

To avoid this, a simple solution would be to adapt the ranges of your gauge by dividing them by 100. Essentially this will lead to the same result as with the script by going the other way around (division by 100 instead of multiplication of 100).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it.  In JSON Input,

```
{ 
       "script" : {       
             "inline" :  "doc['system.cpu.user.pct'].value * 100", 
             "lang" :  "painless" 
    }
}
```

If you are not sure of where, see below.

[image]

The gauge is working fine. (with Percentage Mode on or not)

[image]

You can do the same with `system.memory.used.pct`.

---

Also, keep in mind what **apt-get_install_skill** mentioned in his accepted answer.
It is better to change the `Ranges` values for higher performance.

[image]

Comment: No disrespect, but still, that is not an appropiate solution. In Settings -> Advanced Settings check your format for the percentage values.

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill okay I'll check the setting, and come back to you. thank you.

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill  sorry. where's the setting? :(

Comment: Oh its Management -> Kibana Advanced Settings, my mistake sorry

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill  my percentage format  is `0,0.[000]%`

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill hey will you tell me how I can change this format in answer? I will be happy to accept yours

Comment: Its the default format so thats not the issue. 
Be aware that the executed script is an additional performance decreasement. So I would suggest that you instead adapt your ranges by dividing them by 100. This should get you the same result but without the execution of the script

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill  hey thank you for your advice. You should put your advice as an answer. This will help others as well. :)